# R : name of an object stored in a variable

Tags: r

I have this little problem in R : I loaded a dataset, modified it and stored it in the variable "mean". Then I used an other variable "dataset" also containing this dataset

`data<-read.table() 
[...modification on data...]
mean<-data
dataset<-mean`

I used the variable "dataset" in some other functions of my script, etc. and at the end I want to  store in a file with the name `"table_mean.csv"`

Of course the command `write.csv(tabCorr,file=paste("table_",dataset,".csv",sep=""))`
nor the one with `...,quote(dataset)...` do what I want...

Does anyone know how I can retrieve "mean" (as string) from "dataset" ?

(The aim would be that I could use this script for other purposes simply changing e.g. `dataset<-variance`)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please try making it more reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like the following code does:

```
data1 <- 1:4
data2 <- 4:8

## Configuration ###

useThisDataSet <- "data2" # Change to "data1" to use other dataset.

currentDataSet <- get(x = useThisDataSet)

## Your data analysis.

result <- fivenum(currentDataSet)

## Save results.

write.csv(x = result, file = paste0("table_", useThisDataSet, ".csv"))
```

However, a better alternative would be to wrap your code into a function and pass in your data:

```
doAnalysis <- function(data, name) {

  result <- fivenum(data)
  write.csv(x = result, file = paste0("table_", name, ".csv"))
}

doAnalysis(data1, "data1")
```

If you always want to use the name of the object passed into the function as part of the filename, we can use non-standard evaluation to save some typing:

```
doAnalysisShort <- function(data) {

  result <- fivenum(data)
  write.csv(x = result, file = paste0("table_", substitute(data), ".csv"))
}

doAnalysisShort(data1)
```